# Edit application database in android

Tags: android, sqlite, adb

How can I edit an SQLite database after it has been created and stored on my phone together with the corresponding app? I want to add a new column to the database but I can't figure out how. Is it possible to do this via the adb shell or maybe eclipse? Or in code?

I tried to just update my db-adapter class, but then the app fails at compile time with the following Exception:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: No such columns <column_I_want_to_add>
```

Simply removing and reinstalling the app won't work either.

Here's a link to my db-adapter class if it's of any help. The column I'm trying to add is the MILLIS_COLUMN. [Pastie link.](http://www.pastie.org/private/9ciezcuv0pc8zeuseaxoga)

Linus

Comment: I'm new to android programming, but shouldn't you be able to send an ALTER TABLE command to SQLite via the connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A missing blank was the problem. Uninstalling and reinstalling now works.